# Method to play video in array using dropdown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video, methods, drop-down-menu

I'm new to coding and unity and looking for some help. I'm trying to play a video after selecting it from a drop-down list in unity. I have two (2) scripts, one (1) to play the videos and another for the drop-down list. I'm able to play the videos but I don't know how to select the video from the drop-down list so it plays. I have an array of videos and the drop-down list dynamically populates from the resources folder. After I select a video from the drop-down I get the following error in Unity; **IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is my method code

```
//THIS IS THE METHOD I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH
    public void PlaySeletedVideo()
    {
       for (int videoClipIndex = 0; videoClipIndex <= videoClips.Length; videoClipIndex++)
        {
            videoPlayer.clip = videoClips[videoClipIndex];
            videoPlayer.Play();
        }
```

This is my dropdown code:

```
public class VideoDropdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dropdown dropdown;
    
    void PopulateDropdown(Dropdown dropdown, VideoClip[] optionsArray)
    {
        List<string> options = new List<string>();
        foreach (var option in optionsArray)
        {
            options.Add(option.name);
        }

        dropdown.ClearOptions();
        dropdown.AddOptions(options);
    }
    private void Awake()
    {
        Dropdown myDropdown = GetComponent<Dropdown>();
        VideoClip[] dropdownVideos = Resources.LoadAll<VideoClip>("Videos") as VideoClip[];
        PopulateDropdown(myDropdown, dropdownVideos);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Array indices in c# are `0`-based => the indices go from  `0` to `theArray.Length - 1`!

When iterating arrays in c# you always want to use

```
i < theArray.Length
```

and **not**

```
i <= videoClips.Length
```

Finally, why are you iterating at all? You don't want to go through the entire array and start playing all clips ... You only want to play exactly **one** clip, the selected one so e.g.

```
public void PlaySeletedVideo(int selectedIndex)
{
    videoPlayer.clip = videoClips[selectedIndex];
    videoPlayer.Play();
}
```

Comment: How can I get the forward and backward value to adopt the selected video value so it goes to the next video instead of original position in the array?

Comment: How can I play videos from a web server instead of hosting locally?